# Problem when using form-reference in transform/pivot query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, pivot, transform

When the query is like this there is no problem

This works:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Aktivitet.ID) AS AntalförID
SELECT Aktivitet.region, Sum(Aktivitet.antalMän) AS [Antal Män], Sum(Aktivitet.antalKvinnor) AS [Antal Kvinnor]
FROM Aktivitet
GROUP BY Aktivitet.region
PIVOT Aktivitet.aktivitetstyp
```

But when I add this line I get into trouble:

```
WHERE Aktivitet.datum > Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum
```

This does not work:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Aktivitet.ID) AS AntalförID
SELECT Aktivitet.region, Sum(Aktivitet.antalMän) AS [Antal Män], Sum(Aktivitet.antalKvinnor) AS [Antal Kvinnor]
FROM Aktivitet
WHERE Aktivitet.datum > Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum
GROUP BY Aktivitet.region
PIVOT Aktivitet.aktivitetstyp
```

And I can't figure out why, `Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum` works just fine in a simple `SELECT` query, and if I change `Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum` to `2000-01-01` in the `TRANSFORM/PIVOT` query it works.

The error I get is in Swedish, but it says: "*It's unable to identify Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum as valid fieldname or expression*"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't specify the context where you're running this SQL statement. If it's in code, you need to resolve the form reference before executing the SQL string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a parameter if you wish to refer to a form.

Like so:

```
PARAMETERS Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count(Aktivitet.ID) AS AntalförID
SELECT Aktivitet.region, Sum(Aktivitet.antalMän) AS [Antal Män], Sum(Aktivitet.antalKvinnor) AS [Antal Kvinnor]
FROM Aktivitet
WHERE Aktivitet.datum > Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum
GROUP BY Aktivitet.region
PIVOT Aktivitet.aktivitetstyp
```

As you can see, I am guessing at a data type:

```
PARAMETERS Forms!Sök!aktivitetFrånDatum DateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[Handle parameters](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param)

> parameters do not work with crosstab
>   queries, unless you:
>       a) Declare the parameter, or
>       b) Specify the column headings.
>
> To declare the parameter, choose
>   Parameters on the Query menu. Access
>   opens a dialog. Enter the name and
>   specify the data type.